# NGINX Custom Error page for 504 timeout not working

Tags: nginx

Some of a server operation can be slow and cause a nginx 504 timeout. I am trying to add a custom error page for 502,504 errors but nginx always shows the default error page.

Here is my config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name falsename.name.com
  ssl_certificate path_to_cert;
  ssl_certificate_key path_to_key;
  error_page 502 504 /errors/custom_504.html;
  location /errors/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /errors/404.html;
  }
  location / {
  error_page 502 504 /errors/custom_504.html;
  proxy_pass https://10.0.0.101:8514;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the nginx error log.

Comment: No relevant errors for this server in the error log are generated, even with logging set to warn.

Comment: Turns out the configuration above works, it was the load balancer in front of NGINX which was timing out so the error was sent from that server not the NGINX

Answer (score 2):

Your `error_page` files need to be located under `/usr/share/nginx/html/errors` directory, because nginx appends the path after `location` to the path specified in `root` directive.

Comment: This is true. But it was where I had placed the error_page files.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to write it like this?

```
error_page 502 /errors/custom_504.html;
error_page 504 /errors/custom_504.html;
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, still default 504 page

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the configuration above works, it was the load balancer in front of NGINX which was timing out so the error was sent from that server not the NGINX